# Como criar uma seção de favoritos de imagens com localStorage e Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, localstorage

Preciso criar uma seção de favoritos para mostrar GIF's na tela. Basicamente há um input com um botão de busca utilizando a **API do Giphy**, após clicar no botão irá fazer uma busca e preciso retornar na tela a busca do usuário em um GIF (já fiz essa parte) e após isso quero que quando o usuário clicar em cima de determinado GIF, ele adicione na aba de favoritos (também fiz essa parte), porém estou com alguns problemas.

**1° problema**: Quando o usuário clica em cima do GIF, ele não seleciona especificamente o GIF clicado, ele apenas seleciona e manda para a seção de favoritos o GIF adicionado por último. (Creio que o problema seja que não estou sabendo selecionar de forma precisa o clique).

**2° problema**: Após clicar para adicionar o GIF na aba de favoritos, o GIF é adicionado no array no localStorage, porém ele só aparece na tela após atualizar (F5) a página.

**3° problema**: Na aba de Favoritos quero implementar a possibilidade de ao clicar no GIF, excluí-lo, porém acontece algo semelhante ao **1° problema**. Quando clico no GIF, ele simplesmente exclui o primeiro GIF adicionado à lista e não especificamente o que eu cliquei.

**HTML** -> Aqui posssui toda parte de interação do Javascript com a função de Adicionar e remover GIF's.

```
 <section class="flow__list">
            <div class="flow__list-content">
                <h1>VEJA TODO A NOSSA LISTA DE GIFS</h1>
                <p>Gifs de todas categorias e gostos</p>
            </div>

            <div class="flow__list-container_box">
                    <div id="gif_box" class="flow__list-boxes">
                        
                    </div>
            </div>
            
            <h1>FAVORITOS</h1>
            <div class="flow__list-container_box">
                    <div id="favorites_box" class="flow__list-boxes">
                        
                    </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

**Javascript / Fetch Api**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init); 

function init() {
    document.getElementById("btnSearch").addEventListener("click", ev => {
        ev.preventDefault()
        let url = `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=${APIKEY}&limit=1&q=`;
        let str = document.getElementById("search").value;
        url = url.concat(str);

        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(content => {
            let fig = document.createElement('figure');
            let img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = content.data[0].images.fixed_width.url;
            fig.appendChild(img);
            let gif_box = document.querySelector('#gif_box')
            gif_box.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', fig)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        })
    })
}
```

**Javascript / Adicionar GIF aos favoritos**

```
// Clicar na imagem e adicionar aos favoritos
document.querySelector('#gif_box').onclick = function() {
    const imageSource = document.querySelector('#gif_box img').src

    favorites.push(imageSource)
    alert("Você adicionou aos favoritos")
    localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites))
}
```

**Javascript / Renderizar imagem no HTML na div de 'favoritos'**

```
favorites.map((t) => {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = t;
    document.querySelector('#favorites_box').appendChild(img);
})
```

**Javascript / Remover GIF dos favoritos**

```
// Clicar na imagem dos favoritos e excluir
document.querySelector('#favorites_box').onclick = function () {
    const imagemFonte = document.querySelector('#favorites_box img').src

    const index = favorites.indexOf(imagemFonte)

    favorites.splice(index, 1)
    alert("Você removeu dos favoritos")
    localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites))
}
```

**Informações complementares**: Ao realizar a busca no input aparecerá apenas um GIF por vez na aba de resultado de busca.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Olá, Alves. Importante sempre que postar uma dúvida fornecer um [mcve] do seu problema, e não o código "aplicado" ao uso específico. O site é um repositório de conhecimento para público amplo, é importante que toda postagem seja sobre um problema claro e específico. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70) do site. Eventuais postagens fechadas podem ser reabertas depois de editadas.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

1° problema: com este seu código: `document.querySelector('#gif_box img').src` ele seleciona o primeiro elemento da `#gif_box`, ou seja, a indice `[0]`. Pra resolver isso, eu adicionei um `event` na função de adicionar aos favoritos, para recuperar o `event.target` que basicamente pega exatamente aonde foi clicado. Dessa forma:

```
// Clicar na imagem e adicionar aos favoritos

document.querySelector('#gif_box').onclick = function(event) {
  const imageSource = event.target.src
  // Só adicionara este gif, se ele não já estiver adicionado no array e se o elemento for uma imagem
  if (favorites.indexOf(imageSource) == -1 && event.target.tagName == 'IMG') {
    favorites.push(imageSource)
    alert("Você adicionou aos favoritos")
    window.localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites))

    loadGifs() // mostra na tela sem recarregar
  }
}
```

2° problema: Só aparece na tela depois do `F5` pois você precisa recuperar o novo array no `localStorage` com os novos valores. Então criei essa função assim:

```
function loadGifs() {
  let favorites = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('favorites'))
  document.querySelector('#favorites_box').innerHTML = ''; // Limpando a tela para recuperar os novos valores e valores anteriores novamente

  favorites.map((t) => {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = t;
    document.querySelector('#favorites_box').appendChild(img);
  })
}
```

(outra forma de fazer isso, seria: logo após adicionar no array e guardar no `localStorage`, você usar o `event.target` para pegar qual gif foi clicado e mostrar com um `.appendChild()`

3° problema: Para resolver esse problema de excluir, é a mesma coisa do `primeiro problema`. Basta usar o `event.target`

```
// Clicar na imagem dos favoritos e excluir 
document.querySelector('#favorites_box').onclick = function(event) {
  const imagemFonte = event.target.src;
  
  // Só vai remover se o elemento clicado for uma imagem e existir no array
  if (favorites.indexOf(imagemFonte) !== -1 && event.target.tagName == 'IMG') {
    const index = favorites.indexOf(imagemFonte)

    favorites.splice(index, 1)
    alert("Você removeu dos favoritos")
    localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites))

    loadGifs()
  }
}
```

(outra forma de fazer isso, seria que, logo após remover do array e guardar no `localStorage`, você usar o `event.target` para pegar qual gif foi clicado e remover com o `.remove()`

**POR FIM, O CÓDIGO TODO FICA ASSIM:**

```
let favorites = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('favorites'))

loadGifs()

// Clicar na imagem e adicionar aos favoritos
document.querySelector('#gif_box').onclick = function(event) {
  const imageSource = event.target.src

  if (favorites.indexOf(imageSource) == -1 && event.target.tagName == 'IMG') {
    favorites.push(imageSource)
    alert("Você adicionou aos favoritos")
    window.localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites))

    loadGifs()
  }
}

// Clicar na imagem dos favoritos e excluir
document.querySelector('#favorites_box').onclick = function(event) {
  const imagemFonte = event.target.src;

  if (favorites.indexOf(imagemFonte) !== -1 && event.target.tagName == 'IMG') {
    const index = favorites.indexOf(imagemFonte)

    favorites.splice(index, 1)
    alert("Você removeu dos favoritos")
    localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites))

    loadGifs()
  }
}

function loadGifs() {

  let favorites = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('favorites'))
  document.querySelector('#favorites_box').innerHTML = '';

  favorites.map((t) => {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = t;
    document.querySelector('#favorites_box').appendChild(img);
  })

}
```

Veja como ficou aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/2yufnavL/5/

Comment: `if (window.localStorage.getItem('favorites') === null) {
  window.localStorage.setItem('favorites', '[]')
  window.location.reload()
} else {
  var favorites = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('favorites'))
  loadGifs()
}`

esqueci de avisar: Recomendo colocar este código no começo do arquivo para verificar se existe ou não o item `favorites` no localStorage. Caso não tenha, vai criar, para evitar erro.

Comment: @Caveira Você me ajudou muito. Muito obrigado mesmo! Estou tentando adicionar mais uma aplicação que seria para **inverter a ordem dos meus Gifs favoritos**, por exemplo ao clicar em um botão minhas imagens invertem a ordem e aparecem na tela. Você poderia ajudar nisso?

Comment: @AlvesV É nois mano, tmj! Por nada. Inverter de que forma? Inverter tipo assim?: [1, 2, 3] e DEPOIS de clicar nesse botão ficar: [3, 2, 1]?

Comment: Isso, exatamente assim!

Comment: Vou postar outra resposta aqui

Comment: O exemplo que fiz aqui, foi assim: no HTML, o botão de exemplo: <button id="reverse__favs">INVERTER FAVORITOS</button>

Comment: E a função: function reverseFavorites() {
 let favorites = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('favorites'))
  let favoritesReverse = favorites.reverse();
  document.querySelector('#favorites_box').innerHTML = '';
  
  favoritesReverse.map((t) => {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = t;
    document.querySelector('#favorites_box').appendChild(img);
  })
}

Comment: E o evento: // Clicar no botão de reverter e reverter a ordem
document.querySelector('#reverse__favs').onclick = function () {
 reverseFavorites();
}

Comment: Veja o exemplo: [https://jsfiddle.net/b3rL8t5d/](https://jsfiddle.net/b3rL8t5d/)

Comment: Não está limpo o código,da pra melhorar bastante, fiz apenas o exemplo, vc pode pegar e implementar da melhor forma ai.

Comment: Se quiser salvar os favoritos invertidos, é salvar o `favoritesReverse` no `localStorage.setItem('favorites',JSON.stringify( favoritesReverse))` logo após reverter ele.

Comment: Simplesmente incrível, funcionou perfeitamente! Agora vou para minha última aplicação que tenho que colocar nesse projeto. Que é **organizar os gif favoritados com nome e descrição** acho que essa vai ser a mais complicada, as outras eu estava até conseguindo, porém estava com problemas pra renderizar na tela, essa nem faço ideia como começar kk, nunca fiz algo do tipo.

Comment: É um pouco mais complexo sim, vai precisar mudar o array todo, ou seja, terá array dentro de array. Essa é a única forma que sei. Fica mais ou menos assim: let favorites = [ ['imagem1','nome1', 'descricao1'], ['imagem2','nome2', 'descricao2'], ['imagem3','nome3', 'descricao3'] ]; veja o exemplo: [https://jsfiddle.net/mj8x74ew/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/mj8x74ew/1/)

Comment: Ou seja, let favorites =  [ ['imagem1','nome1', 'descricao1'], ['imagem2','nome2', 'descricao2'], ['imagem3','nome3', 'descricao3'] ]; **se quiser acessar o favorite 1, será assim:** favorites[0]0]; // imagem favorites[0]1]; // nome  favorites[0]2]; // descrição - se quiser acessar o 2, muda apenas o primeiro [], assim: favorites[1][0] // imagem e por ai vai

Comment: É um pouco complexo, não sei se entendeu, vai precisar mudar praticamente o código todo, mas é fácil desde que entenda como funciona